# I'm unable to find why my columns are stacking in HTML/CSS (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently working on putting together a very basic site and using CSS/ Bootstap. I am unable to figure out however why my columns are stacking on each other. I've looked through Stack Overflow and the official bootstrap documentation and as far as I can see, it *should* be working: I am looking to create three equal columns underneath the "about me" header that span the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>Testing | </title>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS-->
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo|Bitter|Copse|Cutive|Lora:700|Sanchez|Scope+One|Slabo+27px|Trocchi|Vesper+Libre" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
    header {
        text-align: center;
        background: url('sunlightthroughgrass.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        color: black;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
    a {
        color: white;
    }
    h1 {
        font-family: 'Vesper Libre', serif;
        font-size: 70px;
    }
    img {
        max-width: 400px;
        max-height: 400px;
        margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
        border: 7px solid white;
        border-radius: 20px;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
    ul {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
    li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    }
    <!-- article {
        max-width: 500px;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
     @media (max-width: 500px) {
        h1 {
            font-size: 36px;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        li {
            padding: 5px;
            display: block;
        }
    }-->
</style>
</head>

<body> 
<div class="container-fluid">
<header>
    <img src="robin.jpg">
    <h1>Test Person|Testing</h1>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Resume</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            Test Test Test
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                Nother Test
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    Third Nother Test
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <!-- SCRIPTS GO UNDER HERE -->
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--Anti-Spam-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/obscure.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nesting your `col-lg-4` divs, do it like this instead:

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            Test Test Test
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            Third Nother Test
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            Third Nother Test
        </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Hi Samir, Thanks for your reply. It seems so obvious now that you've said it. Much appreciated!